# Executing script with sudo in virtual environment - packages not found

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, scapy

I created a virtual environment and wrote a Scapy project in it. For this I wrote some modules and packages and put them in the environments site-packages folder. Now when I enter the environment with `source bin/activate` and try to execute the script with `sudo` some modules I put in the virtual environments site-packages folder can't be found. When I execute it as normal user the module is found, but the script, of course, won't work because it needs super user rights. How can I fix this?

```
(Project)user@pc ~/git/Fuzzing/src $ python BACnetMonitoring.py 
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BACnetMonitoring.py", line 17, in <module>
    webRequest_timeout=1
  File "/home/user/git/Fuzzing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BACnetMonitor.py", line 78, in __init__
    self._socket = conf.L2socket(iface=self._iface)
  File "/home/user/git/Fuzzing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 414, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init__
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
(Project)user@pc ~/git/Fuzzing/src $ sudo python BACnetMonitoring.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BACnetMonitoring.py", line 7, in <module>
    import BACnetMonitor
ImportError: No module named BACnetMonitor
(Project)user@pc ~/git/Fuzzing/src $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` doesn't inherit your environment. Specify the full path to the Project's python executable.

Look at `sys.executable` with and without `sudo`.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. With `sudo` the path is `/usr/bin/python`, without it's `/home/user/git/Fuzzing/bin/python`. That explains why, but still - is there a way to fix this?

Comment: *"is there a way to fix this?"* -- *"Specify the full path to the Project's python executable."* namely: `sudo /home/user/git/Fuzzing/bin/python`

Comment: Thank you, that's actually pretty simple.